# How to ask good question at the end of lecturer interview

Tags: teaching, job, interview

I interviewed yesterday for a lecturer position at computer science. At the end of my interview, the Head of School asked me if I have any questions to ask them. This is my first time to interview, and I don't know what to ask, and just said to the HoS that ``I saw your research project on Youtube, and I was very interested in that topic, and is possible to have any future collaborations?'' I did see his research project on Youtube. However, I can feel that the HoS was not very happy. Maybe I screwed it up. Is this a sensitive question? Could anyone give me some suggestions on how to ask good questions? Thank you.

Comment: When you're being interviewed for *any* job I think it's poor form to ask the interviewer if you can work for them. That puts them in an awkward position, as they haven't even offered you a job yet or had time to reflect on the interview.

Answer (score 4):

One good question to ask is, "What is required for a new lecturer to succeed here?" and the likes. I've asked this myself and the Head of School was very eager to share with me the answer.

Asking people whether they would collaborate with you seems too early, as you will need to show them that you have something to offer.

Answer (score 2):

You should prepare a lot of questions in advance to the interview. Of course make sure that the questions are not answered on the website of the institute/university. During the interview have the list of questions ready and when you asked if you have any questions, either ask the remaining questions that haven't been answered already or say

> I think that all questions I had have already been answered.

However, I do not have a really good  generic general question - I think that the good questions are specific for the place that interviews you.